# How to limit hues to two values when using stacked geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been using RStudio for about 2 weeks, so I might not explain myself well. I'm plotting the x-axis (hosp_visits_2years) against a ratio of insured v uninsured. The values for the insurance are binary (1 and 0), but for some reason the data set I'm using includes a value of -9 as well in that category. I've tried limiting the fill to "0" and "1" with 2 possible hues, but I get Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.

I tried increasing the number of hues to 3, but it includes all three values (0,1,-9)

```
ggplot(oakland_analysis_final, 
       aes(x = hosp_visits_2years, fill = factor(uninsured))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)), position = "fill") + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1"), values = scales::hue_pal()(2)) + 
  xlim(0, 50)
```

[image]

Comment: -9 likely indicates some kind of flag in the data. If there's a code book or data dictionary for your data you will see what it means. It might be relevant to show all three categories - but if you want, you can exclude it. Then you have to filter it out of the data your are feeding into ggplot by filtering out observations with a value of -9, then the rest should work as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the factor `oakland_analysis_final$uninsured` is numeric, the simple solution is probably to exclude any observations where this is equal to -9.  There's a few ways to do that, like by using pipe command `%>%` from `dplyr` and `filter()`.  My preference here is to filter within the `data=` call to `ggplot()`, so try changing your `ggplot()` call to the following:

```
ggplot(oakland_analysis_final[which(oakland_analysis_final$uninsured!=-9),], 
       aes(x = hosp_visits_2years, fill = factor(uninsured)))
```